# Equality Between Set Cardinalities

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Proof - if $A\sim B$ then $P(A) \sim P(B)$ .
( $\sim$ Means there is a bijection between the two sets.)

Isn't it clear that if $A\sim B$ it means that the size of the two sets is equal and so for their power sets?

Comment: If it is clear then tell (prove) it. I don't think it is trivial. By the way, the title of your question is misleading: there is no, and doesn't have to be, equality between any sets in this case

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\;f: A\to B\;$ is a bijection. Define

$$F:P(A)\to P(B)\;,\;\;F(X):=\left\{\,f(x)\;;\;x\in X\,\right\}$$

Prove now $\;F\;$ is a bijection (this is a nice exercise)